# How to connect to secured (Kerberos) Kafka cluster using a node.js and Kafka-node package

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am working on a use case where I need to consume messages from Kafka (0.9.x) using a node.js (v6.9.5) and Kafka-node package. I am using below snippet to connect to Kafka from the node.js.

My Kafka environment is Kerberos enabled. I don't know how to connect to the secured Kafka environment using a node.js. If anybody has done this before, please share the solution.

```
var payloads = [ { topic: 'nodejs_topic' }];
var options = {
    groupId: 'kafka-node-group1',//consumer group id, default `kafka-node-group` 
    // Auto commit config 
    autoCommit: true,
    autoCommitIntervalMs: 5000,
    // The max wait time is the maximum amount of time in milliseconds to block waiting if insufficient data is available at the time the request is issued, default 100ms 
    fetchMaxWaitMs: 100,
    // This is the minimum number of bytes of messages that must be available to give a response, default 1 byte 
    fetchMinBytes: 1,
    // The maximum bytes to include in the message set for this partition. This helps bound the size of the response. 
    fetchMaxBytes: 1024 * 1024,
    // If set true, consumer will fetch message from the given offset in the payloads 
    fromOffset: false,
    //securityProtocol:'PLAINTEXTSASL'
    // If set to 'buffer', values will be returned as raw buffer objects. 
    encoding: 'utf8'
};
var kafka = require('kafka-node'),
    client = new kafka.Client('server-1:2181,server-2:2181,server-3:2181'),
    consumer = new kafka.Consumer(client,payloads,options);

client.on('ready', function(){
  console.log('Client ready!');
});

//console.log(client);
//console.log(consumer);

consumer.on('error', function (err) {
  console.log("Kafka Error: Consumer - " + err);
});

consumer.on('offsetOutOfRange', function (err){
  console.log("Kafka offsetOutOfRange: " + err);
});

consumer.on('message', function(message){
  console.log(message);
});
```

Comment: https://github.com/SOHU-Co/kafka-node/issues/511 I got to know that kafka-node do not support SASL+ Kerberos, Is there any other option to connect node.js and kerberos kafka cluster.

Comment: Badly stuck on this, any help or pointers will be really helpful